# python - documentation on the behavior to expect from list(generator)

Tags: python

Please suggest which documentation to look to understand the behavior of :

```
list(generator)
```

Expected it would raise the `StopIteration` but instead it looks it returns an empty list. Which documentation I should look to understand what behavior to expect?

[Built-in functions -list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list)

> class list([iterable])
> Rather than being a function, list is actually a mutable sequence type, as documented in Lists and Sequence Types — list, tuple, range.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably implement `list` yourself:

```
def list(xs):
    out = []
    for x in xs:
        out.append(x)
    return out
```

...where `for` handles the `StopIteration`. The loop is essentially equivalent to:

```
xs = iter(xs)
while True:
    try:
        x = next(xs)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    out.append(x)
```

The actual code for these is implemented in CPython.